# How generate Java classes from several xsd using JAXB (IntellijIdea)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have three xsd files and they are linked. How can I generate java classes from them? I try using intellij idea, but JAXB allows to select only one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using maven you can use the jaxb2 maven plugin, you can see example of usage here https://memorynotfound.com/generate-java-classes-from-xsd/